# Intercepting and interracting with a custom Error object in javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception

I am using a custom javascript modulue which has it's own `Error` objects. I would like to intercept those custom Error objects and take the appropriate path in my `try{} catch{}` block, distinguishing them from Javascript's built in Error objects such as `ReferenceError`, `TypeError` etc.

So a bit like this.

```
try {
    // Some code that might produce a traditional javascript error
    // or one of the errors raised by the module I am using.
}catch (error){
    if(error instanceof ExchangeError){
        // Handle this in a way.
    }else{
        // Probably one of the built in Javascript errors,
        // So do this other thing.
    }
}
```

So, in the example above, `ExchangeError` is a custom error belonging to that specific module, however, I am not able to run the `instanceof` on my error, despite the fact that when I do `error.constructor.name` I get `ExchangeError`.

My javascript scope simply does not know about that `ExchangeError`. So the question is, how can I intercept those kind of Error objects? I'm sure I can do it with string matching, but just wanted to check if there is a more elegant way.

One thing I tried, I have my own `errors` module, that has some custom errors in there, I tried to mimic the module's Error object:

```
    class ExchangeError extends Error {
        constructor (message) {
            super (message);
            this.constructor = ExchangeError;
            this.__proto__   = ExchangeError.prototype;
            this.message     = message;
         }
     }
```

and import that through my `errors` module, but that did not work obviously.

Comment: `error instance of ExchangeError` should be `error instanceof ExchangeError`

Comment: Yes, in my code it is `instanceof`, so I miss-typed it here in my question. Still, when I do `console.log(error.constructor.name)` I get `ExchangeError` But I can't get this to work `if (error instanceof ExchangeError) { console.log('it is an ExchangeError.') }`

Comment: I think the error is elsewhere in your code. Because the code you've provided should work: https://jsfiddle.net/yquax3tp/1/

Comment: Yes. But, by injecting my own `ExchangeError` I actually was doing something really really bad, I was blinding the `instanceof` check with my own `ExchangeError`, where as the `ExchangeError` that was coming from the module, was NOT an instance of my own `ExchangeError`. I have solved it and will post my answer now. Thanks to @FrankerZ.

Answer (score 0):

By actually implementing my own `ExchangeError` I actually was doing something really really bad, I was blinding the `instanceof` check with my own `ExchangeError`, whereas the `ExchangeError` instance that was coming from the module, was NOT an instance of my own ExchangeError. That is why my `if` check was falling silent.

The solution is simply doing this:

```
     const { ExchangeError } = require ('ccxt/js/base/errors');
```

Importing the error from within the module. Now the `instanceof` look up is working. I did not know that one can import bits and pieces from a module like that.

Thanks to @FrankerZ for pointing that out.